# Chi-square test to check sampled variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have two independent unknown points $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a set of $N$ observations $x_i$, $y_i$ of their positions that I model with a normal distribution: $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma_x)$, $y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(y, \Sigma_y)$, for each $i \in [1, N]$. Covariances $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_y$ are known. I compute the distance between each pair of observations: $d_i = \|x_i - y_i\|$. I would like to test whether all the distances $d_i$ are similar, or if any of them is very different from the others. I have two questions:

1. If I model the distance between points $x$ and $y$ as a random variable $D$ (with samples $d_i$ or $d_i^2$), what distribution fits $D$?
2. I think I can test whether all the $d_i$ are similar with a chi-squared test. For that, I must have an expected variance for $D$, say $\sigma_d^2$, set the null hypothesis to $H_0: \sigma^2 \leq \sigma^2_d$, compute the test statistics $T$ variable and compare with the value of the $\chi^2$ for $N-1$ degrees of freedom. Is this correct, or is any other type of test best suited for this problem?

Comment: In somewhat more conventional usage one might denote the two points $X$ and $Y$ by lower-case letters and the random variables by capital letters.  This makes it possible to understand expressions like $\Pr(U\le u)$ or the difference between $f_U(3)$ and $f_V(3)$ etc. However, concerning the content of your question${}\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$you are testing hypotheses about the distribution from which the data are drawn, and that leads to the question of whether you KNOW the values of the two matrices $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_y$ or do you need to estimate those based on the data? $\qquad$

Comment: If one assumes INDEPENDENCE (which you didn't mention (and people often omit to mention that even when they intended it to be understood)) then $$x_i-y_i \sim \mathcal N(X-Y,\Sigma_x + \Sigma_y),$$ and so $$\left\|(x_i-y_i -(X-Y))^\top \left(\Sigma_x + \Sigma_y)^{-1} (x_i-y_i -(X-Y) \right) \right\| \sim \chi^2_3 \tag 1 $$ for each value of $i$ separately.  You also didn't say whether $X,Y$ are known or have to be estimated based on the data. If you put in data-based estimates of $X$ and $Y$, and of $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_y$, in the expression $(1)$, that certainly alters its distribution.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$also, possibly someone at stats.stackexchange.com might be familiar with some standard approach to this problem, and with its literature. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Michael. I edited the text to clarify that $X$ and $Y$ are unknown and independent but I know (or have a guess at least) $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_y$.
From your third comment, I understand that the difference of each observation follows a normal distribution, and its norm a chi-squared one, right?

Comment: $\quad\uparrow\quad$ but not is Euclidean norm.  I should have written $$ (x_i-y_i -(X-Y))^\top \left(\Sigma_x + \Sigma_y)^{-1} (x_i-y_i -(X-Y) \right) $$ without $\text{“}\|\,\cdot\,\|\text{''}$.  That is a norm of sorts, but it differs from the Euclidean norm, which is $$(x_i-y_i -(X-Y))^\top (x_i-y_i -(X-Y).$$